# What is the difference between Event.target, Event.toElement and Event.srcElement?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    console.log(evt.target, evt.toElement, evt.srcElement);
};
```

By clicking the right mouse button on a `<div class="foo"></div>`, returns this:

> div.foo, div.foo, div.foo

By clicking the right mouse button on a `<input>`, returns this:

> input, input, input

All seem to bring the same result. Is there any situation that one of them has different use than the others?

Answer (score 110):

The [event target](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#glossary-event-target) is the element to which the event is dispatched:

> The object to which an [event](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#glossary-event) is targeted using the [DOM event
>   flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow). The event target is the value of the [`Event.target`](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-Event-target)
>   attribute.

`srcElement` is a IE non-standard way to obtain the `target`.

The [current event target](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#glossary-current-event-target) is the element which has the event listener which is currently invoked:

> In an event flow, the current event target is the object associated
>   with the [event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#glossary-event-handler) that is currently being dispatched. This
>   object MAY be the [event target](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#glossary-event-target) itself or one of its ancestors.
>   The current event target changes as the [event](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#glossary-event) propagates from
>   object to object through the various [phases](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#glossary-phase) of the event flow.
>   The current event target is the value of the
>   [`Event.currentTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-Event-currentTarget) attribute.

Using `this` inside an event listener is a common (and standard) way to obtain the current event target.

Some kind events have a [`relatedTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#widl-MouseEvent-relatedTarget):

> Used to identify a secondary [`EventTarget`](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#interface-EventTarget) related to a UI event,
>   depending on the type of event.

`fromElement` and `toElement` are IE non-standard ways to obtain the `relatedTarget`.

Comment: I'm using "toElement" in Chrome version 60 - are you sure it's a "IE non-standard way"?

Comment: MSDN says it is "non-standard' and "do not use it on production sites facing the web": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement

Comment: the latest chrome supports "toElement" but not Mozilla Firefox.  I had to use 'target' property to support a few cases in Mozilla.