# event.toElement.id always undefined when I trigger event click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am newbie to html and java-script ,trying to fire a click event when page load finished

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $("#london").click(function(event){
       openCity(event,'London');
    });

    $("#london").trigger('click'); //this is automatic click

});
```

This click is working.But in my function

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
   var id = evt.toElement.id; //id is undefined only when click event triggered
}
```

`id` is undefined only when click event triggered,when normal click it contains value.

Comment: did you try $(this).id with openCity(this,'London')

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i will try

Comment: `toElement` is a nonstandard property, and it's only applicable for events like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, not `click`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865416/what-is-the-difference-between-event-target-event-toelement-and-event-srcelemen

Comment: @CLIFFORDPY your welcome:). I hope it works as you wish

Comment: @hsnbl I tried that,but I got the same error

Comment: @CLIFFORDPY it was my bad, you can use  $(this).attr('id') to get id of element or other attributes with attr("AttributeName")

Comment: @hsnbl in your thinking ,i need to pass element is to attr('element-id') right?

Comment: it is optional, you can get it in function or pass it when you call the function

Comment: @hsnbl Yes,I tried that also,it is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of **toElement** you need to use **target**.

For more info I'd suggest to read [What is the difference between Event.target, Event.toElement and Event.srcElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865416/what-is-the-difference-between-event-target-event-toelement-and-event-srcelemen)

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var id = evt.target.id; //id is undefined only when click event triggered
  console.log('id: ' + id);
}

 $("#london").click(function(event){
    openCity(event,'London');
});

$("#london").trigger('click'); //this is automatic click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="london">london</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `evt.target.id` instead of `toElement` - see demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {
  $("#london").click(function(event) {
    openCity(event, 'London');
  });

  $("#london").trigger('click'); //this is automatic click

});

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var id = evt.target.id; 
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='london'>London</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` keyword for your function like following.

```js
function openCity(element, cityName) {
  var id = element.id; 
  console.log('id: ' + id);
}

$("#london").click(function(event){
    openCity(this,'London');
});

$("#london").trigger('click'); //this is automatic click
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="london">london</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You better use `this` inside the function, and then `attr('id')` to get the relevant attribute:

```js
function openCity(el, cityName) {
   var id = $(el).attr('id');
   console.log(id);
}

$(document).ready(function(event){
    $("#london").click(function(event) {
       openCity(this, 'London');
    });

    $("#london").trigger('click'); //this is automatic click
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="london">London</div>
```

`this` in your context is the relevant elements that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to get the *bound* element.

```
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
   var id = evt.currentTarget.id;
}
```

This is a standard property of the `event` object. It yields the same value as `this` would in the handler. That way you can still just pass around the `event` object and have the `target`, the `currentTarget` and all the other event data as well.

Keep in mind that the `target` and `currentTarget` may be two different elements. The `target` is the most deeply nested element clicked, whereas the `currentTarget` is always the bound element.

Since you want the element that has the `id`, using `currentTarget` will be safer. Doesn't matter for the `.trigger()` call, but may for the actual, human clicks if you have nested elements.