# Vue.JS infinite re-rendering on data change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am rendering a bunch of HTML divs (I've named them cells) based on Vue data.

The colour of the cell is dictated by a hex code in the data.

**On mouse over, a function should run to change the colour of the particular cell.**

Here is how the data looks and how the function works at the moment:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cells: [
             {i: 1, hex: '#111111'},
             {i: 2, hex: '#222222'},
             {i: 3, hex: '#ffffff'}
           ]
  },
  methods: {
    mouseOver: function (e){
       this.cells[e.toElement.id].hex = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)).toString(16);
    }
  }
})
```

And here is the code for the v-for which renders the (in this case) 3 cells:

```
<div class='cell'
     v-for="cell in cells"
     :id="cell.i"
     :key="cell.i"
     :style="{ backgroundColor: cell.hex}"
     @mouseenter="mouseOver">
</div>
```

However this does not work.

> *[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.*
>
> *(found in `<Root>`)*

I theorise that this is because Vue re-renders all of the cells every time the data changes, and since the component is new, the function runs again.

However I'm new to Vue and not sure how to go about solving this!

Help much appreciated!

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/mqmyLb?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `#` at the beginning of your hex color code and you forgot to decrease the index for accessing the array by one.

Furthermore, `e.toElement` seems to be unsupported by some browsers. Rather use `e.target` 
[What is the difference between Event.target, Event.toElement and Event.srcElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865416/what-is-the-difference-between-event-target-event-toelement-and-event-srcelemen)

```
this.cells[e.target.id-1].hex = '#' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)).toString(16);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TobiObeck/qfpkvn9L/1/