# How to Target a Child Node Without Knowing Its Position Using Only Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events

I have created a mockup navbar, and using the `mouseenter` event, have been able to display the submenus inside their parent `li` element.

This has been achieved using the `children` property and locating the position of the submenu, but was wondering how this is achieved without knowing so, or if there is a better idiomatic approach.

The submenus and list items have the same class names.

Below, you will find my code:

```js
'use strict';

var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

 e.preventDefault();

 Array.from(dropdown).forEach(function(node) {
  node.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
   event.target.children[1].style.display = 'block';
  });
 });

 Array.from(dropdown).forEach(function(node) {
  node.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
   event.target.children[1].style.display = 'none';
  });
 });

});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header {
 height: 20vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: #000;
}

.navbar {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
}

.navbar > li {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.navbar li a {
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 30px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.menu > li {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 10px 0;
 float: none;
}

li {
 width: 100px;
}

a {
 font-family: Helvetica Neue;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <nav>
  <ul class="navbar">
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">I drop down</a>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://google.co.uk">2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">So do I</a>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">4</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">No effect</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Same here</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You would most likely want to use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` as the `currentTarget` will always refer to the element with the event handler attached, whereas the `target` may be one it's descendants. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31865416/what-is-the-difference-between-event-target-event-toelement-and-event-srcelemen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add `id`s (or `class`es) to the target elements, then add some attribute to the controlling element to express which target element it controls. Without knowledge of the DOM relationship between the two nodes, you're going to have to add some information to connect them.

I was going to use a `data-` attribute, but then I remembered that by using `aria-controls` you could add some a11y too.

```js
'use strict';

var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    Array.from(dropdown).forEach(function(node) {
        node.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
            var menuId = event.srcElement.getAttribute('aria-controls');
            document.getElementById(menuId).style.display = 'block';
        });
        node.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
            var menuId = event.srcElement.getAttribute('aria-controls');
            document.getElementById(menuId).style.display = 'none';
        });
    });

});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    height: 20vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #000;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

.navbar > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar li a {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    float: none;
}

li {
    width: 100px;
}

a {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="dropdown" aria-controls="menu1"><a href="#">I drop down</a>
                    <ul class="menu" id="menu1">
                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://google.co.uk">2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown" aria-controls="menu2"><a href="#">So do I</a>
                    <ul class="menu" id="menu2">
                        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">No effect</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Same here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `aria-controls`!

Answer (score 1):

Another way (one I prefer) would be to use the structure of the HTML to find the nodes. To do this the `ul.menu` must be a descendant of the `currentTarget`. Then you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to locate it.

```js
'use strict';

var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

 e.preventDefault();

 Array.from(dropdown).forEach(function(node) {
  node.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
   this.querySelector(':scope > ul.menu').style.display = 'block';
  });
  node.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
   this.querySelector(':scope > ul.menu').style.display = 'none';
  });
 });

});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

header {
 height: 20vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-color: #000;
}

.navbar {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
}

.navbar > li {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.navbar li a {
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 30px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.menu > li {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 10px 0;
 float: none;
}

li {
 width: 100px;
}

a {
 font-family: Helvetica Neue;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <nav>
  <ul class="navbar">
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">I drop down</a>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://google.co.uk">2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">So do I</a>
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">4</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">No effect</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Same here</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do this either. Thanks