# get xpath of the element on which it is clicked by javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension by which i will be able to get xpath of the element on which it is clicked.
`event.currentTarget` gives me document
and
`event.toElement` gives me whole body tag.
chrome is giving me whole document or body puzzled by this behaviour, am i missing something?

or what are other ways to do that?
please help.

[image]

Comment: `toElement` is an ancient IE-compatible alias for `relatedTarget` so you don't need it. As for the difference between currentTarget and relatedTarget, there are existing answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31866151)).

Comment: thanks for that info but how i will get exactly on which element it is clicked on it it is showing document as currentTarget because i have added  event Listener on whole document.

Comment: Simply use `event.target`, there's no need for currentTarget or relatedTarget at all AFAICT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript

Comment: got answer from my x y co ordinate and got element